# vagrant postgreSQL run COPY

Tags: postgresql, csv, vagrant

I want to COPY rows from a CSV file (From my Mac locally) into my postgreSQL DB, which is running on Vagrant.

As far as I know the `COPY` command can only be runned as super user.

This would be the command which fits:
`COPY part_model FROM '/Users/myusername/Desktop/csv-file-to-import.csv' csv header;`

Then running from my Terminal in the project folder I also have my Vagrantfile and I usually create the vagrant machine, I tried to run this command:

`vagrant ssh -c "sudo su - postgres -c 'psql -d databasename name -U username -h localhost COPY part_model FROM '/Users/myusername/Desktop/part_model-import.csv' csv header'";`

But I get this error/warning:

> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "COPY" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "part_model" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "FROM" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "/Users/antonhorl3/Desktop/part_model- Import.csv" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "csv" ignored
>
> psql: warning: extra command-line argument "header" ignored

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Count the quotes and the double quotes.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for your comment. The quotes all close. But maybe at the wrong place? Not sure where the error is. Maybe you have a hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you notice there are **two pairs** of single quotes?